# Compass - Importing mixins

Tags: sass, compass

I'm using yeoman angular generator for my project.

My folder structure for styles.

```
/styles
  /base
  /components
  /helpers
  /layout
main.scss
```

If I wanted to use any mixins, I need to include them in all the files in the subfolders and in turn it increases the time consumed for "concurrent:server".

Basically I wanted to import all the mixins only in the main.scss, and when I did that and ran the `grunt serve`. I get an error `Aborted due to warnings`.

Someone help me out in decreasing the time consumed for Sass mixins.

Comment: And what were the warnings?

Comment: How can check for the warning?